# How can I transfer the old \partcombine syntax of lilypond to a version newer than 2.1.17?

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to convert a Lilypond file to an actual version. The script `convert-ly` gets stuck at the conversion to version 2.1.17 with the following error:

> \partcombine can not be converted.

I am very new to lilypond and it seems that a lot in the syntax has been changed. I would appreciate very much, if you could help me with transfering the following snippet to a more actual version:

```
\score {
    << 
\context StaffGroup = group <<
   \context Staff = violiniI <<
    \property Staff.midiInstrument = #"violin"
    \property Staff.instrument = #'(lines "Violini I    " "(con sordini)" )
    \property Staff.instr = #"  Vl.I "
    \notes <<
    \context Voice=one \partcombine Voice
        \context Thread=one \violinioneI
        \context Thread=two \violinioneII
>>
>>

>>
>>
}
```

Comment: My kingdom for a fix for our botched jTab support. I've put in the necessary workarounds; if you wouldn't mind, please give some upvotes to the following questions on meta: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/240/133 http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/396/133

Comment: 2.17.1 (seems to be mixed up in your question) is a non-stable development version. I would first try to fall back to stable 2.16.2. The changes document specifies no change in partcombine already present in 2.16.2, so this might be sufficient.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but you missread that. I wrote 2.1.17. - 2.1.16 is the last version I can achieve. In the end I would like to get it to 2.16.0 which I use on Ubuntu, but first, I need to jump over the 2.1.17 specification changes.

Comment: I would recommend finding a friend who does software and asking him/her to write you a `regex`-based script that will swap the old patterns for new.

Comment: I could do that my self. But I need the swap of the old pattern. If someone could transfer above snippet to anything newer than 2.1.16, I'd be happy and could continue. Thank you.

Comment: If it would be an easy regular expression replacement, I'm quite sure, that convert-ly would already handle it. I digged around ancient versions documentation (before 2005??) and while the implementation was changed there, no syntax modification is reported. So I assume, that one should simply double-check the produced result. 2.1.x is also a non-production version. I would replace the lilypond version in the script to 2.2 and give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the link in user6456's answer are 2 links, comparing the old \partcombine with the new one:

Old: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.0/Documentation/user/out-www/lilypond/Automatic-part-combining.html#Automatic%20part%20combining

New: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.4/Documentation/user/out-www/lilypond/Automatic-part-combining.html#Automatic%20part%20combining

Basically the difference in the syntax's being:

Old:`\partcombine context musicexpr1 musicexpr2`

New:`\partcombine musicexpr1 musicexpr2`

The old documentation says:

> The music expressions must be interpreted by contexts whose names should start with one and two.

However the new one says nothing pertaining to that. Which leads me to believe...

Just a sec...

So I tried installing Lilypad, but I don't have the time at the moment to figure out how to use it (and I don't have the version you are wanting to convert to). However, I can make a guess at what is wrong in your code.

Try changing this part:

```
\context Voice=one \partcombine Voice
    \context Thread=one \violinioneI
    \context Thread=two \violinioneII
```

To this:

```
\context Voice=one \partcombine 
    \context Thread=one \violinioneI
    \context Thread=two \violinioneII
```

If the links in user6456's original link are correct, than that should work. However I may be mistaken, for instance those might not be the right versions... Or I might just be mistaken... :) Whatever the case, let me know if this doesn't work.

---

Just in case if you want it all in context, your code should now read:

```
\score {
    << 
\context StaffGroup = group <<
   \context Staff = violiniI <<
    \property Staff.midiInstrument = #"violin"
    \property Staff.instrument = #'(lines "Violini I    " "(con sordini)" )
    \property Staff.instr = #"  Vl.I "
    \notes <<
    \context Voice=one \partcombine
        \context Thread=one \violinioneI
        \context Thread=two \violinioneII
>>
>>

>>
>>
}
```

**Edit:**
I am now having second thought as to if this will work, since the new version of \partcombine documentation also did other things differently:

```
\new Staff \partcombine
```

As compared to:

```
\context Staff <<
         \context Voice=one \partcombine Voice
```

So the change I am suggesting might only work for later versions and if you edit all the rest of the version changes...

**Edit:**

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I came up with this:
[image]

Which was coded with this:

```
\version "2.16.1"
\score {

  violinOne = \relative c' {
    c4 d e f |
  }

  violinTwo = \relative c' {
    g4 a b c |
  }
  \new StaffGroup 
  <<
    \new Staff \with {
      instrumentName = #"Violin 1 "
      shortInstrumentName = #"Vln. 1 "
    } \violinOne

    \new Staff \with {
      instrumentName = #"Violin 2 "
      shortInstrumentName = #"Vln. 2 "
    } \violinTwo

    \new Staff \with {
      instrumentName ="Combined "
    } \partcombine \violinOne \violinTwo
  >>
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try as soon as I can. I think that's tomorrow. All this `\context` and `\property` stuff seems to be old. Property can be replaced by `\set`. That's what I found out so far.

Comment: Just to tell you @LaRiFaRi, I tried compiling it in version 2.16.2 and it failed epicly with a huge log... :) I don't know what the difference is exactly, but I will try to make it work in this version.

Comment: OK, @LaRiFaRi, it seems that `\context` can be replaced by `\new`... I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve, but after playing around with LilyPond (or more with the manual...) I came up with a little something which I will again edit my answer with.

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I will post the exact "translation" of my snippet later, but your answer already did the trick. There are a lot of lines which just can be deleted from this old version.

Comment: Glad to help! This Q/A has made me interested in learning to use LilyPond... Thank _you_! :) I especially like how you can use different types of notation, such as Gregorian chant. Actually, what I am most interested in hasn't yet been implemented... But it has been mentioned: https://code.google.com/p/lilypond/issues/detail?id=1389

Answer (score 2):

After some great help from SuperMusicman, I finally got it to work and I believe, this is the most actual syntax for the snippet from my question.

```
\score {
          <<
        \new StaffGroup  <<
           \new Staff \with {
            midiInstrument = #"violin"
            instrumentName = \markup {
                  \column { "Violini I"
                            \line { "(con sordini)" }
                  }
                }
            shortInstrumentName = #"Vl. I"
           }
            \partcombine
                 \violinioneI
                 \violinioneII 
   ...
   >>
   >>
}
```